# MDB activation for JMS message before the JTA transaction is committed

Tags: jakarta-ee, jms, jta

I need synchronize JTA transaction with send JMS message - MDB should be activated after client JTA transaction commit.
This should by possible when use XAConnectionFactory, but doesn't work in my example.

Example scenario:

- web service client send message with code = 0
- mdb receive message and print: START: code (NEW JTA TRANSACTION)
- mdb increment code and print: SEND: %code + 1%
- mdb send messag with new code value
- mdb sleep
- mdb print: END code
- mdb finish (TRANSACTION COMMIT)

Scenario is repeat until code < 10. I expect result:

```
START: 0
SEND: 1
END: 0
START: 1
SEND: 2
END: 1
START: 2
SEND: 3
END: 2
etc..
```

but currently I get:

```
...
START: 4
SEND: 5
END: 3
START: 5
SEND: 6
END: 4
START: 6
SEND: 7
END: 5
END: 6
```

My code:

- Webservice client

  ```
  @WebMethod
  @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
  public void publish() {
      TestQueueUtil.sendToQueue(0);
  }
  ```
- TestQueueUtil (JMS client)

  ```
  public static void sendToQueue(Integer code) {
    InitialContext initialContext;
    XAQueueConnection queueConnection = null;
    XAQueueSession queueSession = null;

    try {
      Hashtable env = new Hashtable();
      env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory");
      initialContext = new InitialContext(env);
      XAConnectionFactory queueConnectionFactory = (XAConnectionFactory) initialContext.lookup("jms/dsk/ConnectionFactoryXA");

      queueConnection = (XAQueueConnection) queueConnectionFactory.createXAConnection();
      queueConnection.start();

      queueSession = queueConnection.createXAQueueSession();
      Queue queue = (Queue) initialContext.lookup("jms/dsk/TestQueue");

      //QueueSender sender =
      MessageProducer producer = queueSession.createProducer(queue);
      Message jmsMessage = queueSession.createMessage();

      jmsMessage.setIntProperty("code", code);
      producer.send(jmsMessage);
      producer.close();
      queueConnection.stop();

  } catch (Exception e) {
      throw new RuntimeException("sendToQueue", e);
  } finally {
      if (queueSession != null) {
          try {
              queueSession.close();
          } catch (Exception e) {
              //ignore
          }
      }
      if (queueConnection != null) {
          try {
              queueConnection.close();
          } catch (Exception e) {
              //ignore
          }
      }
    }

  }
  ```
- TestQueueMDB

  ```
  @MessageDriven(mappedName = "jms/dsk/TestQueue", activationConfig = {
          @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "acknowledgeMode", propertyValue = "Auto-acknowledge"),
          @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationType", propertyValue = "javax.jms.Queue")
  })
  public class TestQueueMDB implements MessageListener {

      @Resource
      protected MessageDrivenContext messageDrivenContext;

      @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
      public void onMessage(Message message) {
          Integer code = null;
          try {

              code = message.getIntProperty("code");
              System.out.println("START: " + code);
              if (code < 10) {
                  Integer newcode = code + 1;
                  System.out.println("SEND: " + newcode);
                  TestQueueUtil.sendToQueue(newcode);
                  Thread.sleep(2000);
              }
          } catch (Exception e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
          } finally {
              System.out.println("END: " + code);
          }
      }
  }
  ```

What I do wrong ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found that I haven't transaction context on MDB !!!

When I checked transaction ID by calling

```
weblogic.transaction.TxHelper.getTransactionId()
```

received null, and when call messageDrivenContext.getRollbackOnly() get exception

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: [EJB:010156]Illegal attempt to call EJBContext.getRollbackOnly() from an EJB that was not participating in a transaction.
```

Reason of that was annotation

```
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
```

After remove it or change on

```
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
```

all working fine.

:)

Comment: These are very strange symptoms. It's true that MDBs allow only NOT_SUPPORTED or REQUIRED transactional annotations, but I'd rather expect an exception to be thrown upon deployment, than silently ignoring the REQUIRES_NEW. Even so, +1 for interesting follow-up.